# The differential height of the manometer and the force needed to hold the container in place are to be determined

Tags: fluid-mechanics

A cylindrical container equipped with a manometer is inverted and pressed into water. The differential height of the manometer and the force needed to hold the container in place are to be determined

[image]

[image]

Since pression in $A$ is the same as pression in $B$ i got

But since i cant find the value of $d$ i am unable to solve the rest of the exercice. Any suggestions?

Comment: What d? You have D given. But why would you need that? H is related to the pressure by the SG.

Comment: because the pression in A is p(atm)+ρ(SG)*g*h + ρ(air)*g*d and i know that p(atm)=0 but dont know the value of d

Comment: Well since you have just been handed the answer, you won’t learn much since you didn’t work for it.

Comment: but why i dont need the value of d?

Comment: Where is d on your diagram?

Comment: d is the distance that i posted in the figure. Since i was trying to relate the atmosferic pression on top of the tube with the pression of point A

Comment: So why do you think you need d? I gave you a hint - did you not work with that? And your d did not show up too well on my smartphone...

Comment: A less subtle hint than @SolarMike's: write down the values of the densities of water, of the manometer fluid, and of air; then look at the three values next to each other; then think of a one- or two-word natural-language description of the density of air.

Comment: so I dont consider the density of air as its value is very small (when compared to the density of fluid and water) is that?

Comment: @pascal That's what I had in mind, yes: in the hydrostatic balance equations, $d$ is multiplied by the density of air, which can be taken to be zero, rendering $d$ irrelevant.  I should qualify, though, that that argument will fail if $d$ is of the order of $100\,\mathsf{m}$ or larger (i.e. a height ratio so large that it can cancel with the density ratio to something of order unity), which is quite possible in applications (e.g. an air lift pump drilling a hole in the sea bed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the tank is weightless, then

$F = 20\gamma_w A$

$20\gamma_w = \gamma_{mf}h$,

$SG = \dfrac{\gamma_{mf}}{\gamma_w} = 2.1$

Note the tank is pressurized internally by the floating bottom lid "A".

Answer (score 0):

the force need to hold the cylinder down is

$$F=\pi \frac{25^2}{4} 20/1000cm*1.033kg/atm- \text{weight of the cylinder}$$

the difference between the two sides of the manometer is

$$h=20cm/2.1=9.523cm$$

## Edit

responding to OP's comment on how to measure the effective weight of partially submerged cylinder after deducting buoyancy.

$$W_{submerged cylinder}= W_{dry} - \pi *25*20*t$$

- where t is the thicknesses of the cylinder. and weight is in grams.

Comment: how you got those expressions ?

Comment: the pressure of the water at depth d = d*\Rho*g

Comment: and how do you calculate the weight of the cylinder since its partially immerse? (i know its not 6*9.81)

Comment: the weight of cylinder is dry weight - 25pi* thickness* 20 grams.

Comment: and how is that equal to 65N (which is the value I should have) ? if i do what you said i got 1570N

Comment: What is the value of the thickness ? They dont said it in the exercice. And how is that equal to 65N ?